# Qt 4.8: Text on QPushButton becomes selected when window is shown

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, qt4

I have a simple QPushButton being initialized with some very simple code:

```
QWidget window;
// ...

QPushButton button("New Project", &window);
// setGeometry... setStyleSheet...
button.show();
```

But when I launch the application, it appears as if the text in the button is selected like this:

[image: Wierd selected button]

There is nothing related to a bluish tint in the stylesheet, and when I focus on another window on the screen it's normal again:

[image]

It doesn't occur on OS X, but with my Linux install it happens. I presume it's some sort of issue regarding which window is in focus selecting text?

Thanks in advance for any help. :-)

Comment: This looks like the button is selected as the "default". If you haven't explicitly set a style for a selected button, your window manager will set something. Try `setDefault(false)` on the button.

Comment: @arne Nothing different seems to happen with `btn.setDefault(false)`. Maybe there's a property in Qt's stylesheets that'll get rid of the styling.

Comment: 4.8._5_? Can you reproduce this with Qt 5?

Comment: You have `button.show()` instead of `window.show()`, why? :)

Comment: @fasked In the actual source I call both.

Comment: On Linux with fluxbox, QPushButton::clearFocus(); solves this. If this does not help, try to setFocus() on your dialog, mainwindow or centralWidget.

Comment: "Removing" the focus is just a workaround as there are times where you explicitly want the focus. It is more down to the point to avoid the rectangle that comes with the focus, not the focus itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and nearly got mad about it: Simply use a proxy style that prevents the focus rectangle from being drawn.

Create a class like this:

```
class myStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
    public:
        void drawPrimitive(PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption *option,
                           QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
        {
            if (element == QStyle::PE_FrameFocusRect) return;
            QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget);
        }
};
```

Then apply an object of this class as your style:

```
qApp->setStyle(new myStyle);
```